# Alert show some hrefs and others not, i want all hrefs that contain the word

Tags: javascript, arrays, tooltip, href

This js searches for hrefs that contain `page=fleet` in them:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="page=fleet"]');

var hrefs = Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(link){
  return link.href;
});

alert(hrefs.join('\n'));
```

but only some hrefs it show, look this image and you will understand:

[image]

the `<a href="....">` is the same, but why don't the three inside the `a` with class `tooltip` show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the syntax highlighting is trying to tell you, those aren't tags.

Instead, that's a giant `name` attribute that happens to contain text that looks like HTML tags.

Your HTML is messed up and should be fixed.

Comment: humm, i understand the problem now, but this html is not mine =/, im doing a chrome extension to show the links, is there any way to change the javascript to get the hrefs in the name?

Comment: @user2582318: You can parse the attribute value into a detached DOM tree (by setting `innerHTML`), then query it.

Comment: dont know how i can do it, you have some examples and where i can find the specific things to study, so i read and try =x

Comment: @user2582318: `var container = document.createElement('div'); container.innerHTML = someSourceCode; container.querySelectorAll(...)`

Comment: Slaks, if i point mouse over, and in the tooltip i inspect the element, it show correctly ;|
http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/43/97c.png

Comment: @user2582318: Those elements are probably created later (based on the code in the attribute).  You can't get elements that don't exist yet.